# Getting weird values reading text files, getting infinite values output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The program is outputting "The average GPA of the female students is:-1.#IND" instead of what it should actually put out. My .dat file is formatted like:
  
f 2.4
  
f 2.6
  
m 3.5
  
etc.
I want it to output the average GPA of those values, but the variables "avgfGPA" and "avgmGPA" are ending up as "-1.#IND"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void openFiles(ifstream& inFile, ofstream& outFile)
{
inFile.open("finalin.dat");
outFile.open("finalout.dat");
outFile << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
inFile >> fixed >> showpoint >> setprecision(2);
if (!inFile||!outFile)
{
cout << "Problem opening file.";
}
}
void initialize(int &countFemale,int &countMale,float &sumFemaleGPA,float &sumMaleGPA)
{
countFemale=0;
countMale=0;
sumFemaleGPA=0;
sumMaleGPA=0;
}
void sumGrades(ifstream& inFile, float &sumFemaleGPA, float &sumMaleGPA,int &m,int &f)
{
sumFemaleGPA=0;
sumMaleGPA=0;

if (!inFile)
{
    inFile.open("finalin.dat");
}
char sex;
float grade;    

while(!inFile.eof())
{

inFile >> sex >> grade;

switch (sex)
{
case 'f': sumFemaleGPA= (sumFemaleGPA + grade);
     f++;
    break;
case 'm': sumMaleGPA= (sumMaleGPA + grade);
    m++; 
     break;
}
}
void averageGPA(float &avgfGPA, float &avgmGPA, int &m, int &f, float &sumFemaleGPA, float &sumMaleGPA)
{
avgmGPA=0;
avgfGPA=0;

avgfGPA=sumFemaleGPA/f;
avgmGPA=sumMaleGPA/m;
}

void printResults(float &avgfGPA, float &avgmGPA, ofstream& outFile)
{
    cout <<"The average GPA of the female students is: "<<  avgfGPA << endl;
    cout <<"The average GPA of the male students is: "<< avgmGPA;

    outFile << "The average GPA of the female students is: "<<  avgfGPA  << endl;
    outFile <<"The average GPA of the male students is: "<< avgmGPA;

}

    int main()
{

int countFemale;
int countMale;
float sumFemaleGPA;
float sumMaleGPA;
float avgfGPA; 
float avgmGPA;

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

openFiles(inFile,outFile);
initialize(countFemale,countMale,sumFemaleGPA,sumMaleGPA);
sumGrades(inFile,sumFemaleGPA,sumMaleGPA,countMale,countFemale);
averageGPA(avgfGPA,avgmGPA,countMale,countFemale,sumFemaleGPA,sumMaleGPA);
printResults(avgfGPA,avgmGPA, outFile);


}
```

Comment: You're still making the same mistakes from the previous question. You should probably apply those corrections first.

Comment: I changed those variables, however it is still not giving me the solution that I want. I suspect it may be something with .eof, or that while loop?

Comment: Examine your while (!inFile.eof) loop very carefully...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with references, or lack thereof:

This code:

> void averageGPA(float avgfGPA, float avgmGPA, int m, int f, float
>   sumFemaleGPA, float sumMaleGPA) { avgmGPA=0; avgfGPA=0;
>
> avgfGPA=sumFemaleGPA/f; avgmGPA=sumMaleGPA/m; }

Should be

...removed solution (homework)

To be clearer, C++ is different from Java in that you need to pass values [by reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr233.htm&ei=qzLgTtDUBeOJsgLI9P3GBg&usg=AFQjCNEv7lj4NAap5LfxFccHeBSebox8ew&sig2=XRLjFwoEudeac4srYW5iow) if you want them to change elsewhere

Comment: I edited my previous code by adding references, I am still getting odd values that are not correct. I cannot see what else is going on, I suspect it may be a problem with the .eof or while loop. My professor recommended we use .eof to be able to read files with unknown length.

Comment: Read my comment on your OP about the logic behind reading file content. It should be a little different than you've written it.

Comment: Great! Good luck in your studies!